# Core Plot generating a flat line, X or Y range incorrect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-plot

I am using core plot to plot about 2000 data points.  They load fine, but I only see a smooth line:

[image]

I am not sure why it is just a flat line rather than showing a graph of all of my values which are in a large range.  Have I done something wrong with setting up the plot space?

```
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(num_points)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(num_points)];
```

Here is my numberForPlot method as well:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    NSNumber *num = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:index];
    return num;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand how this frameworks works, but it looks like you are making both your range and domain go from 0 to the number of data points you have (1500 I am guessing?).  Maybe if you had a proper range and domain, the points would spread out and would not appear to be the line you have.

Comment: I think you are right.  How would I calculate a proper range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of different issues here:

1. The plot space ranges are given in data coordinates. You can either calculate the ranges yourself or use the plot space method `-scaleToFitPlots:` to calculate them automatically. See my answer to [your related question](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/287137e60109fba7/7e3611143e570551?show_docid=7e3611143e570551) on the Core Plot discussion board for how to calculate the ranges manually.
2. Your `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` ignores the *field* parameter. You're returning the same value for both **CPScatterPlotFieldX** and **CPScatterPlotFieldY**, hence the diagonal line.

One possible solution:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    NSNumber *num = nil;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
    case CPScatterPlotFieldX:
        num = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
        break;
    case CPScatterPlotFieldY:
        num = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:index];
        break;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Eric

Comment: Thank you, this really helped and I am able to get a normal looking graph now.